# Online Rails Development Environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Are there any online rails development environments (similar to what Heroku Gardens was like ) before they shut down?

I'm looking for a fully hosted solution similar to what pythonanywhere provides for pydjango.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heroku Gardens. Just to clarify -- you're looking for a place to actually do your development work in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Cloud9

http://cloud9ide.posterous.com/introducing-heroku-support

it does what you want